# Trouble booting server from GRUB prompt

Tags: linux, centos, grub2

I just installed CentOS 6.2 on my server but it keeps going to the GRUB prompt.  I've never used Grub before but did some digging online.  Looks like I have to run the `kernel` command before I can boot the system.  However, the kernel command is not running.  As I installed the OS I checked the box that said something like "Install boot loader on /dev/sda".  The following is what I've done:

```
grub> find /vmlinuz-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64
   (hd1,0)

grub> root (hd1,0)

grub> kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 root=/dev/sda1

Error 27: Unrecognized command
```

I've tried it with and without the root=/dev/sda1, just /dev/sda, also tried a `ro` inserted in the middle but nothing works.  I've read the docs but at a bit of a loss.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest writing a real question... not "any suggestions?"

Comment: The question is 'How to boot the server', as noted in the title.  I've had my questions downgraded in the past for not showing what I have tried thus far.  I'm trying to boot the server and have attempted to do so with the following approach...

Answer (score 1):

Your missing commands, which is the main reason your having this problem.
I also recommend entering your commands from the edit screen, and then booting with CTRL-X

here is an example, I would assume you will have to change things to fit your installation.

```
    root (hd1,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-92.1.22.el5 ro root=LABEL=/
    initrd /initrd-2.6.18-92.1.22.el5.img
```

If this doesn't point you in the right direction, or you have another error message, comment under this and I will help more in depth.

Also worth mentioning, I believe the default GRUB installed with CentOS is still legacy GRUB.  So make sure you don't end up trying answers that are for GRUB2

Comment: I'm still getting a 'Error 27: Unrecognized command' when I run 'kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 ro root=LABEL=/'

Comment: Did you do the `initrd` section?, And enter these commands from the edit menu. Don't try and do this from the rescue prompt.

Comment: The rescue prompt is all I have.  I'm on the console of the box, so I'm not aware of another way to do so.  What file do I put after initrd?  The one you have listed?

Comment: NO, you need to use the filename corresponding to those installed already.  what do you mean console of the box?  The console is what is called when your running Linux.  I assume you mean the GRUB rescue prompt, what happens when you reboot? Do you get any menu at all?

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the rescue prompt.  I've yet to get a login prompt for teh box.  I did an install of CentOS on the box and each time I boot the box I am left at the Grub prompt.  I do not get a menu, least I do not believe I do.  The box is in a datacenter that I cannot access very easily.  Is there a way to reboot the box again from Grub?  I'll try the initrd command as well at this point....

Comment: I get the following error with initrd:   Error 19:  Linux kernel must be loaded before initrd.

Comment: ... Yes it needs to be in the correct order, such as I provided.
How did you botch your install?  The installation wizard (anaconda) is so advanced these days, it should have handled all this automatically.  Is it possible for you to boot the install media again, and do just a grub rescue?

Comment: BTW, did you make grub on its own partition, or HD?  Is this a dual boot machine?

Comment: I can try.  Can you reboot from the grub rescue prompt?  Those who guard the datacenter with their life are gone for the day..  How do I do a grub rescue?  I just followed the install GUI with no problems.  I even got the 'congratulations, you installed CentOS' screen to appear before the reboot.

Comment: I believe the name of the file is `initramfs-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.img`, but i could be wrong about version.  And it could be located somewhere slightly different, its usually like this `initrd /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.img`

Comment: I'm not sure how grub was installed?  I essentially did what this site shows in step 17.  http://www.php2s.com/linux/howto-downloa-install-centos-6-2-step-by-step-guide-screenshots.html   BTW: initrd still doesn't work with /boot at the front, I believe the kernel commdn must successfully run first, which appears to be the crux of the problem.

Comment: The command is `reboot`, ... try pressing escape during boot, to bring up the grub menu from hidden.  Actually if you enter command line  mode, try pressing escape there also.

Comment: At the command line, you can use tab-completion for almost everything. When entering a command, pressing `tab` will get you a command name.  When entering a file, pressing `tab` will get you a filename. When entering a hard disk partition, pressing `tab` will get you a valid partition name.  If you don't get the right one immediately, I think pressing `tab` again will get you the next one.

Comment: Pressing 'tab' is giving me the filenames I have for kernel and other commands, so I'm quite shocked that the command will not take and gives the error noted.  I'll try a reboot and report back sometime tomorrow, as my day is coming to an end at this point.  Thanks for the help so far, hopefully we'll get to the bottom of this....

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to boot the server, nor was anyone else on site who knows anything about Linux.  We re-did the install and accepted the default values CentOS provided after selecting the 'Use all Space' option.  Apparently not setting your own custom partitions worked.  I've set partitions hundreds of time on other systems with no issues but this CentOS install did not like this.  Unsure if anyone else has run into this or not but it is something to consider if anyone else runs into the same issue when performing an install the way I did.

Answer (score 0):

You were using documentation for grub-legacy with grub2. they are not compatible.